# How can I get Value of json object when Object name is dynamic?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I am using promo pricing api of domain name in my asp.net mvc project using c#. I want to get the resellerprice of specific product key like 'dotgold'. In this Api object names are dynamic like 59,58 and so on. How can i do this. Below are json objects of that api...

```
{
  "59": {
    "customerprice": "528.00",
    "timestamp": "2017-02-10 13:59:16.711147+00",
    "actiontype": "addnewdomain",
    "resellerpricecurrencysymbol": "INR",
    "resellerpricetwo": "748.00",
    "isactive": "true",
    "starttime": "1486393372",
    "productkey": "dotjetzt",
    "creationdt": "1486735157",
    "promoid": "13333",
    "serviceprovidersellingcurrency": "INR",
    "istrickleallow": "true",
    "resellerpriceone": "489.50",
    "resellerid": "683272",
    "barrierprice": "680.0",
    "period": "1",
    "endtime": "1491004799",
    "resellerprice": "445.0"
  },
  "58": {
    "customerprice": "302.50",
    "timestamp": "2017-02-10 13:59:16.711147+00",
    "actiontype": "addnewdomain",
    "resellerpricecurrencysymbol": "INR",
    "resellerpricetwo": "451.00",
    "isactive": "true",
    "starttime": "1486393234",
    "productkey": "dotgold",
    "creationdt": "1486735157",
    "promoid": "13332",
    "serviceprovidersellingcurrency": "INR",
    "istrickleallow": "true",
    "resellerpriceone": "264.00",
    "resellerid": "683272",
    "barrierprice": "410.0",
    "period": "1",
    "endtime": "1491004799",
    "resellerprice": "240.0"
  }
}
```

Below is the code to desrialize the json objects

```
string redirect = @"https://test.httpapi.com/api/resellers/promo-details.json?auth-userid=xxxx&api-key=xxxxxxxxxxxx";
string html;
var headers = new System.Net.WebHeaderCollection();
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(redirect);
request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    html = reader.ReadToEnd();
}

var stuff = JObject.Parse(html2);
```

Comment: It's really hard to help you without knowing how you're deserializing JSON in general, or what the JSON looks like. Please provide a [mcve] - and note that this isn't ASP.NET-specific, so a console app will make it easier to demonstrate.

Comment: I have given json obejcts

Comment: But you've provided no code for what you've tried so far, and the JSON you've provided is far from minimal - we don't need to see 18 properties for each value, just enough to make a representative sample.

Comment: Now there's some code, but it was originally *awfully* formatted - please use the preview to make sure a post looks how you want it to look before you hit submit. Now, most of the code you've given is about how you get the JSON as a string, which isn't terribly important - but at least you've shown that you're using `JObject.Parse`. Now you could then just iterate over all the properties in the `JObject`, or you could deserialize to a `Dictionary<int, SomeClass>` instead.

Comment: If you don't want to create a concrete class type for your JSON then you can use ExpandoObject and treat this as dynamic. But it will be good if you can create a class and manage properties that you would like to have. And then deserialize it accordingly to type Dictionary<int, YourClassType> using Json.NET's JsonConvert.Deserialize method.

Comment: Thank you everyone for guidance and support..

Answer (score 0):

Install `Newtonsoft.Json` nuget package if you haven't already.
Then use it to deserilize the json into a `Dictionary<int, Product>` where product is your dto class. You can also deserialize to `Dictinoary<int, dynamic>`

Here is  an example

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Deserialize
{
    public class ProductDto
    {
        public decimal customerprice { get; set; }
        public DateTime timestamp { get; set; }
        public string actiontype { get; set; }
        public string resellerpricecurrencysymbol { get; set; }
        public string resellerpricetwo { get; set; }
        public string isactive { get; set; }
        public string starttime { get; set; }
        public string productkey { get; set; }
        public string creationdt { get; set; }
        public int promoid { get; set; }
        public string serviceprovidersellingcurrency { get; set; }
        public bool istrickleallow { get; set; }
        public decimal resellerpriceone { get; set; }
        public int resellerid { get; set; }
        public decimal barrierprice { get; set; }
        public string period { get; set; }
        public long endtime { get; set; }
        public decimal resellerprice { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var json = "{" + Environment.NewLine +
                "  \"59\": {" + Environment.NewLine +
                "    \"customerprice\": \"528.00\"," + Environment.NewLine +
                "    \"timestamp\": \"2017-02-10 13:59:16.711147+00\"," + Environment.NewLine +
                "    \"actiontype\": \"addnewdomain\"," + Environment.NewLine +
                "    \"resellerpricecurrencysymbol\": \"INR\"," + Environment.NewLine +
                "    \"resellerpricetwo\": \"748.00\"," + Environment.NewLine +
                "    \"isactive\": \"true\"," + Environment.NewLine +
                "    \"starttime\": \"1486393372\"," + Environment.NewLine +
                "    \"productkey\": \"dotjetzt\"," + Environment.NewLine +
                "    \"creationdt\": \"1486735157\"," + Environment.NewLine +
                "    \"promoid\": \"13333\"," + Environment.NewLine +
                "    \"serviceprovidersellingcurrency\": \"INR\"," + Environment.NewLine +
                "    \"istrickleallow\": \"true\"," + Environment.NewLine +
                "    \"resellerpriceone\": \"489.50\"," + Environment.NewLine +
                "    \"resellerid\": \"683272\"," + Environment.NewLine +
                "    \"barrierprice\": \"680.0\"," + Environment.NewLine +
                "    \"period\": \"1\"," + Environment.NewLine +
                "    \"endtime\": \"1491004799\"," + Environment.NewLine +
                "    \"resellerprice\": \"445.0\" " + Environment.NewLine +
                "  }," + Environment.NewLine +
                "  \"58\": {" + Environment.NewLine +
                "    \"customerprice\": \"302.50\"," + Environment.NewLine +
                "    \"timestamp\": \"2017-02-10 13:59:16.711147+00\"," + Environment.NewLine +
                "    \"actiontype\": \"addnewdomain\"," + Environment.NewLine +
                "    \"resellerpricecurrencysymbol\": \"INR\"," + Environment.NewLine +
                "    \"resellerpricetwo\": \"451.00\"," + Environment.NewLine +
                "    \"isactive\": \"true\"," + Environment.NewLine +
                "    \"starttime\": \"1486393234\"," + Environment.NewLine +
                "    \"productkey\": \"dotgold\"," + Environment.NewLine +
                "    \"creationdt\": \"1486735157\"," + Environment.NewLine +
                "    \"promoid\": \"13332\"," + Environment.NewLine +
                "    \"serviceprovidersellingcurrency\": \"INR\"," + Environment.NewLine +
                "    \"istrickleallow\": \"true\"," + Environment.NewLine +
                "    \"resellerpriceone\": \"264.00\"," + Environment.NewLine +
                "    \"resellerid\": \"683272\"," + Environment.NewLine +
                "    \"barrierprice\": \"410.0\"," + Environment.NewLine +
                "    \"period\": \"1\"," + Environment.NewLine +
                "    \"endtime\": \"1491004799\"," + Environment.NewLine +
                "    \"resellerprice\": \"240.0\"" + Environment.NewLine +
                "  }" + Environment.NewLine +
                "}";

            var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<int, ProductDto>>(json);

            foreach (var v in values)
            {
                var poductId = v.Key;
                var product = v.Value;
                Console.WriteLine(poductId + " " + product.resellerpriceone);
            }
        }
    }
}
```